# Issue with Spaces, Desktops reassign themselves

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, desktop, ventura

I have a MacBook Pro running macOS Ventura 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a).

[image: Screenshot of three Spaces showing Desktop 1 through 3]

I use three Desktops like in the picture above and they are numbered 1-3. I have assigned various apps to either of these Desktops. I unplug the laptop and it goes into sleep mode. After I plug it back in the next day the Desktops are numbered 4, 5, and 6. The assignment of the apps doesn't work anymore.

For example, when I try to use my Mail app that was assigned to the former Desktop 3 the window of the Mail app will be force-moved to the new Desktop 4. When I move the Mail app window back to the third Desktop (formerly 3, now 6) and try to click anything in the window it force moves back to the first Desktop that now is number 4. This happens to the other apps which were assigned to Desktops 1-3.

It appears that macOS is trying to move the app windows to the assigned Desktops which do not exist after the unplugging. I am also not sure if the unplugging is the reason or if it is the laptop going into sleep mode.
A restart of the laptop resolves the issue but this is not a proper solution for me.

What causes this issue? How can this be resolved?

[image: Screenshot of the Desktop & Dock System Settings]

Comment: "unplug the laptop" You use two displays? Can you show us your settings in this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcUp6.png

Comment: I use one display. The laptop is always closed and connected via usb c with the display. I edited the post with the settings.

Comment: To better clarify, are you using the MBP's internal display *and* an external display connected via USB-C simultaneously or are you just using a single external display with the lid closed (closed clamshell)?

Comment: I use a single external display with the lid closed.

Comment: The only way I can see this happening is if the internal display is turned on, even briefly and the number of spaces doubles.  It just doesn't renumber desktop spaces in this manner on a single display